1С: как сравнить в запросе тек элемент с предыдущим, необходимо написать запрос который посчитает разницу между днями рождениями из регистра сведен
не понял как сделать перебор
ДеньРождение КАК СледующийДеньРождения,
РАЗНОСТЬДАТ(ДеньРождение, СледующийДеньРождения, ДЕНЬ) КАК КоличествоДней

как задать хороший вопрос

постараюсь задавать лучше вопросы

Сам не пользовался этой конструкцией. Попробуйте следующее: в Конфигураторе установите точку останова на строке Построитель.Выполнить(); Запустите отчет, когда выполнение остановится на точке, сделайте шаг, после чего в Табло добавьте Построитель.Результат и посмотрите какой тип у этого значения; Вы сможете сделать перебор по Построитель.Результат методом предусмотренным для типа этого значения (надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Пробовал не получается, подскажите пожалуйста, если бы у Вас стояла задача, найти разницу в днях рождения, используя запрос. Как бы вы сделали запрос? По заданию в регистре сведений два измерения. Первое ФИО, второе дата рождения. Видимо необходимо использовать вложенные запросы

@Pavel, а в чем заключается разница? Не пойму, что именно требуется в задании. Есть пример?

Как я понял из коммента в

регистре 2 измерения* ФИО, ДатаРождения и необходимо найти разницу в
днях рождения.

Эта задача довольно сложная для начинающего ... Вам необходимо к первой таблице Т1(РегистрСведений) выполнить ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ ПО Т1.ДеньРождения <= Т2.ДеньРождения
где Т2(тот же РегистрСведений) и вычислить разность дат (Т2.ДеньРождения - Т1.ДеньРождения) взять от нее МИНИМУМ()
ВЫБРАТЬ Т1.ФИО, Т1.ДеньРождения, МИНИМУМ(Т2.ДеньРождения - Т1.ДеньРождения)

ИЗ НашРегистрСведений КАК Т1

ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ НашРегистрСведений КАК Т2

ПО Т1.ДеньРождения <= Т2.ДеньРождения 

СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО Т1.ФИО, Т1.ДеньРождения

Следует учитывать случай когда после Т1.ДеньРождения уже нет данных; Тогда необходимо учесть это при вычислении разности
МИНИМУМ(
ВЫБОР КОГДА Т2.ДеньРождения ЕСТЬ NULL ТОГДА 999999 
ИНАЧЕ Т2.ДеньРождения - Т1.ДеньРождения 
КОНЕЦ)

Ну и наконец при выводе отчета 999999 заменять на " "
